# How to get correct TimeZone in googlesheet using script?

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, javascript, time-zone

I have wrote following script in my google sheet hoping to convert a timestamp in GMT to a customized timezone.

```
function myFunctions(datetimeString,timeZone,format) {
  var moment = new Date(datetimeString);
  return Utilities.formatDate(moment, timeZone, "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'")
}
```

However, I have no idea why this function doesn't give me a correct timezone ! For instant, 6/30/2019 6:32:00 should return June 30, 2019 11:02 AM in (GMT+4:30), However, it returns wrong time (June 30, 2019 02:02).

I've wrote the script in script tools, and call myFunctions in googlesheet's cell (consider my timestamp is in A1):

```
=myFunctions(A1,Aisa/Tehran,"dd-MM-yyyy'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'")
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please add the timezone to the input date. If the input date is cell value, the timezone is the spreadsheet timezone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To pass strings as arguments to a custom functions they should be quoted enclosed.

Instead of

```
=myFunctions(A1,Aisa/Tehran,"dd-MM-yyyy'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'")
```

use

```
=myFunctions(A1,"Asia/Tehran","dd-MM-yyyy'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'")
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. However, it doesn't work ! In fact I get a time conversion, but it's not correct ! It shows another time which is not the one I expect ! 
I'm not sure why it gives me a wrong timezone !!! Is it a bug ?